# CSS Grid not loading correctly

Tags: css, css-grid

All of my JavaScript seems to work based on my tests, but the CSS grid-template-columns seems to not be capturing or something?  I had it working before not sure what happened...

If I input "10" into the prompt which creates 100 divs - the screen only creates 100 rows in one single column --it should be creating 10 columns and 10 rows....

Any idea what's happening?

[CODE](https://codepen.io/anna_whiskey/pen/xxdrEZZ)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  padding: 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat (10, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat (10, 1fr);
  gap: 2px;
  margin: none;
}

.boxes {
  background-color: black;
}

.boxes:hover {
  background-color: rgb(194, 243, 250);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` value expressions are syntactically invalid: you have a space between `repeat` and `(`. [The CSS Grid specification's syntax rules do not allow for a space to be located there](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#repeat-syntax).

(Also, it's `margin: 0;`, not `margin: none;`. `none` is for `border`).

Change your CSS to this and it works:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    padding: 0;

    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1fr);
    gap: 2px;
    margin: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!  Now my issue is figuring out how to have the grid rows/columns adjust based on the user input(prompt) (i.e if user inputs "30" - it should change to 900 divs in a 30 by 30 grid.... don't suppose you know how do to that with plain js?

Comment: @Anna-Delta `yourElement.style.gridTemplateColumns = 'repeat( ' + n + ', 1fr )';`